# Does Islam prohibit smoking Marijuana?

Tags: smoking

In Islam, drinking alcoholic is strictly prohibited. Moreover, it has been mentioned clearly by GOD in several locations in Quran and no-one can argue why and ask for more explanations because it is clear.

So what I want to ask is (does Islam prohibit Marijuana?) So far, I came from Arabic background and I lived almost 20 years in an Arabian country and I've been Muslim by born. I have asked several qualified religion-people about it and they always try to avoid it. I searched also a lot in this area and did not get any useful understanding.

one may say "That which intoxicates in large quantities is prohibited in small quantities." (Abu Dawud, Tirmidhi, Ibn Majah, and others, with a sound chain of narrators)

I am 100% convinced that smoking normal tobacco cigarets that we buy from groceries are Haram because it has been scientifically approved that nicotine and other ingredients in cigarets can destroy several parts in the human body. While Marijuana has not (it has very few bad things - the harm that you got as same as you got when you do anything for a long time even if it not harmful even in small amount - as eating two banana everyday considered harmful # actually anything you eat or smell is harming you in such a way and in various percentages). so we finished from this argument

and if you still saying it is haram, **WHY GOD DID NOT MENTIONED ANY THING ABOUT IT IN QURAN** ? it can be easily prohibited by mentioning 2 words as alcohol. Right?

Users who uses Alcoholic can't understand 'conversation' well, can't drive, cant' deal with any thing sensitive,can't study and can be ended up in a very bad situation. In opposite, weed don't do any of the above (I am telling you this after 5 years experience in this field). So please I need a descriptive answer that is not abusing anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Alcoholic drinks are not the only type of intoxicants that is prohibited, rather it is every intoxicant:

> Ibn 'Umar reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying: Every intoxicant
>   is Khamr and every intoxicant is forbidden. He who drinks wine in this
>   world and dies while he is addicted to it, not having repented, will
>   not be given a drink in the Hereafter.

You may argue that Cannabis is not an intoxicant, but this goes against what medical practitioners define Cannabis as, in [this medical dictionary](http://%20http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/marijuana)  it is described as an intoxicant. The Prophet (pbuh) also gives a definition of what is an intoxicant:

> Al-Bukhaari (4087) and Muslim (1733) narrated that Abu Moosa said: The
>   Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) sent Mu’aadh ibn
>   Jabal and me to Yemen, and I said: O Messenger of Allaah, there is a
>   drink that is made in our land and is called al-mizr, which is made
>   from barley, and another drink called al-bit’, which is made from
>   honey. He said: “Every intoxicant is haraam.”

The idea of expecting every impermissible act to be listed in the Quran is absurd, We know what is considered to be Permissible and that which isn't. Allah has gifted us with intellect to come to a conclusion:

> On the authority of Abu 'Abdullah al-Nu'man bin Bashir (ra) who said:
>   I heard the Messenger of Allah(sas) say: "The halal is clear and the
>   haram is clear, and between them are matters unclear that are unknown
>   to most people. Whoever is wary of these unclear matters has absolved
>   his religion and honor. And whoever indulges in them has indulged in
>   the haram. It is like a shepherd who herds his sheep too close to
>   preserved sanctuary, and they will eventually graze in it. Every king
>   has a sanctuary, and the sanctuary of Allah is what He has made haram.
>   There lies within the body a piece of flesh. If it is sound, the whole
>   body is sound; and if it is corrupted, the whole body is corrupted.
>   Verily this piece is the heart." Bukhari & Muslim

A similar question was asked on [Islam QA](https://islamqa.info/en/66227)

Comment: Actually all of the given examples are produced under certain conditions (not naturally produced) while cannabis are made by god and we harvest it as any other crops. So that's why I am saying it will be more acceptable if quran mention it.

Comment: @Krebto that is irrelevant, whether something is considered an intoxicant or not does not depend on whether it is naturally produced or not.